# Rounding Behavior When Converting from Double to String in PowerShell 5.1

Tags: c#, powershell, type-conversion

When converting from double to a string using [string], strange rounding behavior seems to occur in PowerShell 5.1.

Converting 0.114338713266919499 to a string becomes 0.11433871326919, indicating that it rounds the ...499 down to zero and truncates. This behavior doesn't seem to match rounding in C# , so I am struggling to duplicate this behavior as the rounding doesn't seem to follow any convention I can find. I found the [conversions page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-06?view=powershell-7.3) for powershell but it has no details on how the conversion works under the hood. I am trying to duplicate the values generated by a script using a double to string conversion in C# and cannot change the script. Any details on the conversion process would be appreciated.

I tried a variety of double values and it seems to keep 15 digits after the decimal not including zeroes after the decimal but before non-zero values. However, when I go to C# and ask it to round the 15th decimal place, I find different results. I understand the floating point numbers are not exact values, but it seems since they are the same range in C# and PowerShell for doubles that I should be able to duplicate the behavior.

Comment: Floating point inaccuracies?

Comment: It probably isn't rounding at all.  Just truncating.  If you want rounding then call a rounding method.

Comment: It is rounding, if you test a few values you can see the rounding in action

Comment: What method are you using to convert it to string?

Comment: double only supports a precision of 15 digits (most of the time) and this is what is happening here.  have a look at this blog page for more detail https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-numbers-in-powershell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This edge case "discrepancy" is crazy because it depends if you are compiling for the .NET Framework or .NET Core 1.0-2.1 or .NET Core 3.0+ **AND** the platform (x86 vs. x64) that you are compiling it for. Your C# code needs to be compiled with the same .NET Framework/.NET Core version and platform that matches the PowerShell version and platform and it's .NET compilation ([PowerShell and .NET versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.3#net-framework-vs-net-core)).

TLDR: This has been fixed in .NET Core 3.0+ where they actually fixed it and made floating points [IEEE 754-2008 compliant](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/). I would recommend migrating all C# code to .NET 3.0+ and using PowerShell 7.0+ (.NET 3.1) in order for everything to match the "correct" IEEE standard.

There is an issue with the [Round Trip Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#round-trip-format-specifier-r) specifier `R` in the .NET Framework, and .NET Core 1.0-2.2 where:

> In some cases, Double values formatted with the "R" standard numeric
> format string do not successfully round-trip if compiled using the
> `/platform:x64` or `/platform:anycpu` switches and run on 64-bit systems.

Some Examples.

### PowerShell 5.1 running x64 .NET Framework 4.5

`$a` Returns Truncated value `19`

`R` returns wrong full precision `1949`

`G17` returns correct full precision `1949`

```
PS C:\> [double] $a = '0.114338713266919499'
PS C:\> $a
0.114338713266919

PS C:\> '{0:R} R' -f $a
0.11433871326691949 R
PS C:\> '{0:G} G' -f $a
0.114338713266919 G
PS C:\> '{0:G15} G15' -f $a
0.114338713266919 G15
PS C:\> '{0:G16} G16' -f $a
0.1143387132669195 G16
PS C:\> '{0:G17} G17' -f $a
0.11433871326691949 G17
```

### PowerShell 5.1 running x86 .NET Framework 4.5

`$a` Returns Truncated value `19`

`R` returns correct rounded precision `195`

`G17` returns wrong rounded precision `195`

```
PS C:\> [double] $a = '0.114338713266919499'
PS C:\> $a
0.114338713266919

PS C:\> '{0:R} R' -f $a
0.1143387132669195 R
PS C:\> '{0:G} G' -f $a
0.114338713266919 G
PS C:\> '{0:G15} G15' -f $a
0.114338713266919 G15
PS C:\> '{0:G16} G16' -f $a
0.1143387132669195 G16
PS C:\> '{0:G17} G17' -f $a
0.1143387132669195 G17
```

### PowerShell Core 6.1.3 running x64 .NET Core 2.1

`$a` Returns Truncated value `19`

`R` returns wrong full precision `1949`

`G17` returns correct full precision `1949`

> .NET Core 2.1 matches .NET Framework 4.5 results.

```
PS C:\> [double] $a = '0.114338713266919499'
PS C:\> $a
0.114338713266919

PS C:\> '{0:R} R' -f $a
0.11433871326691949 R
PS C:\> '{0:G} G' -f $a
0.114338713266919 G
PS C:\> '{0:G15} G15' -f $a
0.114338713266919 G15
PS C:\> '{0:G16} G16' -f $a
0.1143387132669195 G16
PS C:\> '{0:G17} G17' -f $a
0.11433871326691949 G17
```

### PowerShell Core 7.2.7 running x64 .NET 6.0

`$a` Returns Truncated value `19`

`R` returns correct rounded precision `195`

`G17` returns correct full precision `1949`

```
PS C:\> [double] $a = '0.114338713266919499'
PS C:\> $a
0.114338713266919

PS C:\> '{0:R} R' -f $a
0.1143387132669195 R
PS C:\> '{0:G} G' -f $a
0.1143387132669195 G
PS C:\> '{0:G15} G15' -f $a
0.114338713266919 G15
PS C:\> '{0:G16} G16' -f $a
0.1143387132669195 G16
PS C:\> '{0:G17} G17' -f $a
0.11433871326691949 G17
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not PowerShell issue, it is the nature of floating point numbers and also the 15-17 digits limit is the same at .Net. Take a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types).
Generally it's an issue (if we can call it so) with any code that uses floating point numbers, e.g. in any language that uses IEEE 754.
Test this code and you will get false!

```
double myVar = 22.3;
Console.WriteLine((myVar + .1) == 22.4);
```

It means if you see a double variable with value `22.3` it is not actually that precise value but just an approximation.
Just use decimal data type if you are working with precise decimal values.

Comment: I understand this, doubles are stored as an exponent and mantissa. When it converts to a string though, it is rounding this value. I am hoping someone knows how PowerShell handles this conversion. I am unable to change the PowerShell script and am trying to duplicate its functionality

Comment: It uses the standards. Consider this code in .net: double myVar = 0.114338713266919499;
Console.WriteLine(myVar); The same result is shown. So you can refer to Double.ToString documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-7.0

Comment: Thank you for the link, hugely helpful!

Comment: @MDZand it was interesting to discover that Microsoft only got around to 'fixing' their floating point implementation to be [IEEE 754-2008 compliant](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/) in .NET Core 3.0+. That means that we need to run PowerShell 7.0+ to have "correct" IEEE 754 implementations that we can rely on. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74622402/2150063) below.